# Recurrence Relation Confusion

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Consider the recurrence relation $$a_{n + 1} = \frac{n - 2}{n^2 - 3n - 4} a_n$$  It seems that all $a$'s with index greater than or equal to $3$ would end up as $0$, regardless of the numeric value of $a_0$, because $a_3 = 0$, and each $a$ indexed after that is ultimately a product involving $a_3$.  However, as has been pointed out in the comments, this would be overridden for $a_4$ and higher indices because the denominator of the recurrence relation is undefined at $n = 4$.

However, the solution given by Wolfram (after lumping constants and assuming $n$ an integer) is $$a_n = A\frac{(n - 4)(n - 3)}{n!}$$  This is defined and nonzero for $n \geq 5$ so long as the constant $A$ is nonzero.  What is going on here?

I noticed that by making the substitution $n = m + 10$, yielding $$a_{m + 11} = \frac{m + 8}{m^2 + 17m + 66} a_{m + 10},$$ Wolfram's answer remains the same, but the zeros and undefined points of the recurrence relation are numerically different.  Is Wolfram doing this or something else to infer what the recurrence relation solution *should* be for larger values of $n$?

Comment: Isn't this only defined for $n\geq 5$, since $n^{2}-3n-4=0$ for $n=4$?

Comment: @JoshuaWang has an important point - when you get to $a_5$ you find yourself computing $\frac 00$ so you can't say that all the values with large index are zero - you run into undefined territory.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know what you did provide to Wolfram Alpha. If you write (have a looh [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5B%7Ba%5Bn+%2B+1%5D+%3D%3D+%28n+-+2%29%2F%28n%5E2+-+3+n+-+4%29+a%5Bn%5D%2C+a%5B0%5D+%3D%3D+A%7D%2C+a%5Bn%5D%2C+n%5D))

> RSolve[{a[n + 1] == (n - 2)/(n^2 - 3 n - 4) a[n], a[0] == A}, a[n], n]

the given result is (using Pochhammer symbols)

$$a_n=\frac{ (n-4) (n-3)}{1440\,\, (6)_{n-5}} A=\frac{ (n-4) (n-3)}{12 \, n!}A$$ and the sequence is
$$\left\{A,\frac{A}{2},\frac{A}{12},0,0,\frac{A}{720},\frac{A}{1440},\frac{A}{5040},
   \frac{A}{24192},\frac{A}{145152},\frac{A}{1036800},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: That Wolfram solution matches what I got (up to lumping constants).  My concern with this answer is that $\frac{A}{720} = \frac{n - 2}{n^2 - 3n - 4} 0$ is incorrect.